# RSpec test not hitting view with render_view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rspec

I am getting this error when using RSpec to test an index action and response in a Rails controller:
    `JSON::ParserError:
       A JSON text must at least contain two octets!`

The most common fix -- including `render_views` -- is not working and `nil` is not being passed in. The test is not hitting the view. When I insert `render json: {test: 'hello world'}, status: 200 and return` in the index action of the controller, and a pry in the view (`index.json.jbuilder`) and after the `get :index` in the test, I can see there is a response body. If I amend the test expectation to `expect(response).to render_template '[]'` I can see the empty array that should be in the response body. Why is render_views failing and how to I get it working again?

Here is the index_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ThingsController, type: :controller do
  render_views
  let(:json_response) { JSON.parse(response.body) }
  let(:status) { response.status }
  let(:user) { create(:user_with_associations) }
  subject{ ThingsController }

  describe "GET #index" do
    context "(success cases)" do
      before(:each) do
        expect_any_instance_of(subject).to receive(:set_user_by_token).and_return(user)
      end

    context "and when there are no things" do
      before(:each) do
        get :index
      end

      it "returns a 200 status" do
        expect(status).to eq 200
      end

      it "returns a top level key of data with an empty array" do
        expect(json_response["data"]).to eq []          
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require_relative 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

And here is the spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'faker'

include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before do
    FactoryGirl.factories.clear
    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
  end
end
```

And here's the controller action under test things_controller.rb:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :index ]
  before_action -> {check_last_updated("Thing")}, only: [ :index ]

  def index
    @things = @current_user.things.in_last_three_months.approved_and_unapproved.order(start_time: :asc)
  end
end
```

Rails 4.2.0
Ruby 2.1.2
RSpec 3.5.4

This is my first question here, so let me know if there is other information that should be included.

Answer (score 2):

You're not correctly stubbing out the authentication in your spec. You say

```
expect_any_instance_of(subject).to receive(:set_user_by_token).and_return(user)
```

but you should say

```
allow_any_instance_of(subject).to receive(:set_user_by_token).and_return(user)
```

As a general rule, `*_any_instance_of` methods should be avoided if possible because [they can be ambiguous](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance) in more nuanced situations. In controller specs, you can use `controller` to access the instance of the controller being tested. e.g.

```
allow(controller).to receive(:set_user_by_token).and_return(user)
```